# What is a "roving" backdoor?

Tags: malware, privacy, intrusion, spyware, backdoor

What is a "***roving***" backdoor?
I understand the general concept of a backdoor.
*Emphasis on keyword qualifier: "**roving**"...*

Comment: What is the context? I had a google just to settle my own curiosity, but could only find the term 'roving backdoor' in relation to this question.

Comment: This is probably going to sound pretty stupid but I actually heard it twice, just now, during dialogue from "Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles". The context was a fairly typical "hacker" type scenario; where someone or something gains unauthorized access to a remote system via the Internet. Obviously the show is based in science fiction but I have heard the term used before and in the same context. I've also heard it used in similar (but different) contexts and in a similar fashion; generally regarding: covert surveillance operations, espionage, eavesdropping, wire-tapping etc.

Comment: "The agents tell him that several nights earlier he accessed the computer networking system, which allows access to military industrial systems. Young Fischer denies the charge, and we see via flashbacks that it was actually older Fischer who got through security and installed a "roving backdoor" to the systems which the government still cannot remove." http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_209:_Complications

Comment: "I've traced the ***"roving"*** *backdoor* that allowed access to my systems. It uploaded itself from one of the main T3 hubs that carry all global internet traffic.. It is highly sophisticated.. The *backdoor* allowed the insertion of a worm program. The worm is merely code, a means by which the intelligence can invade and operate my systems remotely.. I calculate that the worm is now present in a significant percentage of the world's computer systems.." [terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_220:_To_the_Lighthouse](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_220:_To_the_Lighthouse)

Answer (score 6):

In the context you provide, it has to do with a backdoor that changes or moves over time. There might be a backdoor on port 8000, then it switches to port 8001, etc. The idea is that once a backdoor is discovered, the hacker must re-discover it to use it again.

See also the concept of "[port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking)" in real life, where the backdoor only opens once you trigger it with a sequence of steps.

Answer (score 3):

In surveillance I believe the concept of 'roving' is down to the court order placed on an individual.

For example; If an authority, be it the police, intelligence or security services is issued a roving surveillance order by a court to tap your phone, then they tap your phone, but then you dispose or make inactive that phone, then the order will allow tapping of further devices that belong to you, without having to re-apply for a further court order. So the authority can continue monitoring your communications.